# arduino robot wont move

Tags: arduino-uno

I wanted to build an object avoider robot and I am a beginner so I copied a video from youtube and did exactly the same thing and used the same code but when I upload the code the robot won't move at all and it makes a weird sound. i cant I identify if this is a coding problem or hardware problem please tell me what is wrong and what I should do. previously I had made the same robot it moved but the coding was wrong and while adjusting it the minus and plus met at the positive terminal and smoke came I quickly turned it off and this resulted in my batteries getting wasted. do you think that this might be the reason might have added some things extra but they are not connected to the motor driver or Arduino here is the pics of my robot
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1t9eYnCt_v4w-IAjYex5wKEFwKv91hnAr?usp=sharing
.here is my code

````
//ARDUINO OBSTACLE AVOIDING CAR Video - https://youtu.be/h-B42_HXL00//
// Before uploading the code you have to install the necessary library//
//AFMotor Library https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-motor-shield/library-install //
//NewPing Library https://github.com/eliteio/Arduino_New_Ping.git // 
//Servo Library https://github.com/arduino-libraries/Servo.git //
 
#include <AFMotor.h>  
#include <NewPing.h>
#include <Servo.h> 
 
#define TRIG_PIN A0 
#define ECHO_PIN A1
#define MAX_DISTANCE 100 
#define MAX_SPEED 150 // sets speed of DC  motors
#define MAX_SPEED_OFFSET 20
 
 
NewPing sonar(TRIG_PIN, ECHO_PIN, MAX_DISTANCE); 
 
AF_DCMotor motor1(1, MOTOR12_64KHZ); 
AF_DCMotor motor2(2, MOTOR12_64KHZ);
AF_DCMotor motor3(3, MOTOR34_64KHZ);
AF_DCMotor motor4(4, MOTOR34_64KHZ);
Servo myservo;   
 
boolean goesForward=false;
int distance = 100;
int speedSet = 0;
 
void setup() {
 
  myservo.attach(10);  
  myservo.write(115); 
  delay(2000);
  distance = readPing();
  delay(100);
  distance = readPing();
  delay(100);
  distance = readPing();
  delay(100);
  distance = readPing();
  delay(100);
}
 
void loop() {
 int distanceR = 0;
 int distanceL = 0;
 delay(40);
 
 if(distance<=25)
 {
  moveStop();
  delay(100);
  moveBackward();
  delay(200);
  moveStop();
  delay(200);
  distanceR = lookRight();
  delay(200);
  distanceL = lookLeft();
  delay(200);
 
  if(distanceR>=distanceL)
  {
    turnRight();
    moveStop();
  } 
 
  else
 
  {
    turnLeft();
    moveStop();
  }
 } 
 
 else
 {
  moveForward();
 }
 distance = readPing();
}
 
int lookRight()
{
    myservo.write(50); 
    delay(500);
    int distance = readPing();
    delay(100);
    myservo.write(115); 
    return distance;
}
 
int lookLeft()
{
    myservo.write(170); 
    delay(500);
    int distance = readPing();
    delay(100);
    myservo.write(115); 
    return distance;
    delay(100);
}
 
int readPing() { 
  delay(100);
  int cm = sonar.ping_cm();
  if(cm==0)
  {
    cm = 250;
  }
  return cm;
}
 
void moveStop() {
  motor1.run(RELEASE); 
  motor2.run(RELEASE);
  motor3.run(RELEASE);
  motor4.run(RELEASE);
  } 
 
void moveForward() {
 
 if(!goesForward)
  {
    goesForward=true;
    motor1.run(FORWARD);      
    motor2.run(FORWARD);
    motor3.run(FORWARD); 
    motor4.run(FORWARD);     
   for (speedSet = 0; speedSet < MAX_SPEED; speedSet +=2) // slowly bring the speed up to avoid loading down the batteries too quickly
   {
    motor1.setSpeed(speedSet);
    motor2.setSpeed(speedSet);
    motor3.setSpeed(speedSet);
    motor4.setSpeed(speedSet);
    delay(5);
   }
  }
}
 
void moveBackward() {
    goesForward=false;
    motor1.run(BACKWARD);      
    motor2.run(BACKWARD);
    motor3.run(BACKWARD);
    motor4.run(BACKWARD);  
  for (speedSet = 0; speedSet < MAX_SPEED; speedSet +=2) // slowly bring the speed up to avoid loading down the batteries too quickly
  {
    motor1.setSpeed(speedSet);
    motor2.setSpeed(speedSet);
    motor3.setSpeed(speedSet);
    motor4.setSpeed(speedSet);
    delay(5);
  }
}  
 
void turnRight() {
  motor1.run(FORWARD);
  motor2.run(FORWARD);
  motor3.run(BACKWARD);
  motor4.run(BACKWARD);     
  delay(500);
  motor1.run(FORWARD);      
  motor2.run(FORWARD);
  motor3.run(FORWARD);
  motor4.run(FORWARD);      
} 
 
void turnLeft() {
  motor1.run(BACKWARD);     
  motor2.run(BACKWARD);  
  motor3.run(FORWARD);
  motor4.run(FORWARD);   
  delay(500);
  motor1.run(FORWARD);     
  motor2.run(FORWARD);
  motor3.run(FORWARD);
  motor4.run(FORWARD);
  }```
````

Comment: forget about obstacle avoidance ... write a simple sketch to move motors forward for 1 second, stop for 1 second, then repeat

Comment: I recognize that robot chassis - its the one I started with as well!  I second the commenter's recommendation.  Don't worry about anything beyond getting the motors to move.  In fact, I would recommend you disconnect all but one motor, and replace the wheel from that motor with a piece of tape (so you can see if it is rotating).  That way the robot will be supported by the three non-moving wheels and you can see motor rotation without having the robot run away.

Comment: You might also want to consider a different power source, other than the 9V batteries you show in your pics.  These batteries are very poor motor sources as they have relatively low capacity.  If you have a DC power supply, use it instead.  If not, be prepared to change out batteries often.  See my blog site (fpaynter.com) for some additional information on 2 and 4-wheel robots.

Comment: Please don't link to Google Drive. Those pictures will disappear, and then people won't understand your question (and perhaps the answer) in the future. You can edit your post and upload the relevant pictures through the editor. Keep the amount of pics minimal though.